# divide image to regions , assign them labels? use pointers

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an image , lets's say 800x800 pixels and I want to define regions of 200x200 pixels and be able to process them.

I can't figure how to make this work.
I tried:

```
int N = 4;
Size smallSize( graySize.width / N ,graySize.height / N );

Mat region_frame;
vector<Mat> smallImages;

namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
for( int i = 0; i < graySize.height - N; i+= smallSize.height )
{
    for( int j = 0; j < graySize.width - N; j+= smallSize.width )
    {
        Rect rect = Rect( j,i, smallSize.width, smallSize.height );
        region_frame = grayImg( rect );
        smallImages.push_back( region_frame.clone() ); 

        imshow( "Display window", region_frame );           
        waitKey(0);


    }
}
```

But I am receiving no output ( no windows is created!).
If I use imshow to the grayImg ,it is showed correctly.

Also ,because I want to work on these blocks/regions/subimages ,is there a way to assign them a label?
For example region[0] ( which will contain pixels 0-199 x 0-199 , region[1] 200-399 x 200-399 and so on.

*********EDIT****************

So , the problem for not showing the image was that above the code I had:

```
if( grayImg.isContinuous() )
{
    graySize.width *= graySize.height;
    graySize.height = 1;
}
```

removing that , the image is shown ok!

Now , remains the handling of smallImages in order to be able to make computations.

For a Mat object I can do for example

```
float *theData = (float*)grayImg.data;
```

But for a `vector<Mat>` like smallImages?
How can I use a pointer?

Comment: What is happening? I just tested it and it's working...

Comment: @Berriel:It just doesn't produce any output.It behaves like not calling imshow.But ,if I use imshow for the original image ( outside the loop) it shiws correctly.

Comment: @Miki: I saw this post and already used the 'correct' code even though this post has not an accepted answer.Also , I am asking something else in the last paragraph.

Comment: So you want a "label" image where each region has the same label?

Comment: I just copy-n-paste your code, added the `imread`, and it's working... About your last paragraph: `smallImages` will be a vector of regions, so you can use `smallImages[x]` as you want

Comment: try smallImages.push_back( region_frame.clone() )

Comment: Also, `Size` is `width` and `height`, not viceversa. You need to change the line to `Size smallSize( graySize.width / N ,graySize.height / N );` or it won't work for non-square images

Comment: @ sturkmen: Thanks ( I had it like that before posting). Still not working.( I will check your answer but I wanted something more simple)

Comment: @Miki:Ok , thank you.

Comment: Sorry but it's still not clear to me which output do you expect. You want an image of `graySize` where each "region" has the same label number?

Comment: @George I posted a working example on what I understood you want. Please let me know if I undertood correctly, so that I can provide a solution that fits your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store each subimage into the `smallImages` without cloning:

```
// Creates a new Mat header that "points" to the subimage
smallImages.push_back(grayImg(rect));
```

you can directly access the subimage into the main image as usual, like:

```
// Change the 3-rd subimage to be all 127
smallImages[2].setTo(127);
```

or using pointers (example in the code below).

Example code:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat3b img = imread("D:\\SO\\img\\nice.jpg");
    resize(img, img, Size(800, 800));

    Mat grayImg;
    cvtColor(img, grayImg, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    grayImg.convertTo(grayImg, CV_32F);

    int N = 4;

    if (((grayImg.rows % N) != 0) || ((grayImg.cols % N) != 0))
    {
        // Error
        return -1;
    }

    Size graySize = grayImg.size();
    Size smallSize(grayImg.cols / N, grayImg.rows / N);

    vector<Mat> smallImages;

    for (int i = 0; i < graySize.height; i += smallSize.height)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < graySize.width; j += smallSize.width)
        {
            Rect rect = Rect(j, i, smallSize.width, smallSize.height);
            smallImages.push_back(grayImg(rect));

            //imshow("Display window", grayImg(rect));
            //waitKey(0);
        }
    }

    // Change the 3-rd subimage to be all 127
    smallImages[2].setTo(127);

    // Iterate on all pixels in 2-nd subimage (will change also the main image)
    int idx_smallimage = 1;

    float* pdata = (float*)smallImages[idx_smallimage].data;
    int step = smallImages[idx_smallimage].step1();

    for (int i = 0; i < smallSize.height; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < smallSize.width; ++j)
        {
            // Assign a random value to pixel (i,j) in subimage
            pdata[i * step + j] = rand() & 255;
            //smallImages[idx_smallimage](i * smallSize.width + j) = rand()&255;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By saying labels , I really mean to be able to work in every subimage.So, I have to use `smallImages' for that .Can you please let me know how can I handle the `smallImages` as pointers?Because for a Mat object I can do `float *theData = (float*)grayImg.data;`.But for a `vector<Mat>` like `smallImages`?

Comment: @George changed the answer. Let me know

Comment: How can I do sth like : `smallImages[ i*smallSize.width+j ] `.Thank you!

Comment: @George check again... let me know

Comment: :This works ok , but as I told you , how can I use pointers instead of smallImages?An for example `cout << smallImages[idx_smallimage](i * smallSize.width + j)` doesn't work.Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: :Also , I noticed that if we use Mat and not Mat1b as you used, then this solution doesn't work.So, If we have Mat ?

Comment: @George if you have a `Mat`, you need to use `.at<uchar>(...)`. See updated code. Which pointers are you talking about? Do you want the pointers to refer to the main image instead of the small image? In that case, why?

Comment: :If for example I have the `Mat greyImg` , I can use `float *theData = (float*)grayImg.data;` and then use theData for my computations.So , can I do the same for `vector<Mat1b> smallImages;` ?I want to do it for speed and because I like it better.

Comment: :Ok!One last!If I want to see the float contents of smallImages ..Just use `(float)pdata[i * step + j]`.Is there a way to cast it before?As `uchar* pdata`? Because if I use float instead of uchar it doesn't work.

Comment: in this example `grayImg` and so all subimages are of type `CV_8UC1`, so you need to use `uchar`. If you have them of type `CV_32FC1`, then you can simply change the line to: `float* pdata = (float*)smallImages[idx_smallimage].data;`, or `float* pdata = smallImages[idx_smallimage].ptr<float>(0);`

Comment: :Yes,I changed to `grayImg.convertTo( grayImg , CV_32FC1 );` and then used `float* pdata = (float*)smallImages[idx_smallimage].data`.But ,using `pdata[i * step + j]` in the loop gives me `OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!fixedType() || ((Mat*)obj)->type() == mtype) in create, file /build/opencv/src/opencv-2.4.12.2/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 1365
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/opencv/src/opencv-2.4.12.2/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:1365: error: (-215) !fixedType() || ((Mat*)obj)->type() == mtype in function create
`

Comment: @George you probably messed up something. Check new code. It works ok

Comment: :Yes!If you define `grayImg` and `smallImages` as `Mat1b` it gives the error above.Else,It works fine, thank you very very much for the help ( voted and accepted).

Comment: :Hmm.Just something last that I saw now!Since we divided the original 800x800 image to sub images of 200x200 ,then the `pdata` for every `idx_smallimage` will go from 0-199?Or, for `idx_smallimage = 0` , pdata will go 0-199 , for `idx_smallimage=1` , pdata 200-399 and so on?Because right now ,for example for `idx_smallimage=0` , I can access `pdata[ 1234 * 200 + 199 ]`!!!! ( step = 200 ).I would expect either access until ` 199 * 200 + 199 ` either `799 * 200 + 799` (sub images goes through all image?).I hope you understand.(sorry for the trouble..)

Comment: :1000 apologies..If just you can explain me my last comment , I 'll be grateful.Sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

you can test the code i already implemented. maybe you will change it according to your needs.

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

class ImageCells
{
public:
    ImageCells(int rows, int cols, int width, int height);
    virtual ~ImageCells() {}

    int cellwidth() const {return m_width;}
    int cellheight() const { return m_height;}
    int cols() const { return m_cols;}
    int rows() const { return m_rows;}

    void setCell( int col, int row, Mat img );
    void setImage( Mat img );
    Mat getCell( int col, int row );
    Mat image;

protected:
    int  m_width;
    int  m_height;
    int  m_cols;
    int  m_rows;
};

ImageCells::ImageCells( int rows, int cols, int width, int height)
{
    image = Mat::zeros( rows * height, cols * width, CV_8UC3);
    m_width = width;
    m_height = height;
    m_cols = cols;
    m_rows = rows;
}

void ImageCells::setCell( int col, int row, Mat img )
{
    if(img.cols == m_width & img.rows == m_height)
    {
        Mat roi = image( Rect(col * m_width, row * m_height, m_width, m_height) );
        img.copyTo(roi);
    }
}

Mat ImageCells::getCell( int col, int row )
{
    Mat roi = image( Rect(col * m_width, row * m_height, m_width, m_height) );
    return roi.clone();
}

void ImageCells::setImage( Mat img )
{
    if(img.cols >= image.cols & img.rows >= image.rows)
    img.copyTo(image);
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    ImageCells cells(4,3,70,90); // it creates a ImageCells class having 4 rows and 3 cols, cell witdh = 70 cell height = 90 you can change these values according your needs

    Mat img = Mat( 90, 70, CV_8UC3,Scalar(0,0,255)); // a test mat to use with cells.setCell important note is : img witdh&height must be same to cell witdh&height

for(int i=0; i < cells.cols(); i++)
    for(int j =0; j < cells.rows(); j++ )
{
   cells.setCell(i,j,img); // here you see how to use  setCell
   randu(img,30*i,160*j); // to show purpose changes img
   imshow("cells.image",cells.image);
   waitKey();
}

for(int i=0; i < cells.cols(); i++)
    for(int j =0; j < cells.rows(); j++ )
{
    imshow("cells",cells.getCell(i,j)); // here you see how to use  getCell
    waitKey();
}
    return 0;
}
```