# from float array to mat , concatenate blocks of image

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an image 800x800 which is broken down to 16 blocks of 200x200.

(you can see previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34117419/divide-image-to-regions-assign-them-labels-use-pointers/34118302?noredirect=1#comment55991859_34118302))

These blocks are : `vector<Mat> subImages;`

I want to  use float pointers on them , so I am doing :

```
float *pdata = (float*)( subImages[ idxSubImage ].data );
```

1) Now, I want to be able to get again the same images/blocks, going from float array to Mat data.

```
int Idx = 0;
pdata = (float*)( subImages[ Idx ].data );
namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

for( int i = 0; i < OriginalImgSize.height - 4; i+= 200 )
{
    for( int j = 0; j < OriginalImgSize.width - 4; j+= 200, Idx++ )
    {

        Mat mf( i,j, CV_32F, pdata + 200 );
        imshow( "Display window", mf );          
        waitKey(0);

    }
}
```

So  , the problem is that I am receiving an

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed

in imshow.

2) How can I recombine all the blocks to obtain the original 800x800 image?
   I tried something like:

```
int Idx = 0;
pdata = (float*)( subImages[ Idx ].data );

Mat big( 800,800,CV_32F );    
for( int i = 0; i < OriginalImgSize.height - 4; i+= 200 )
{
   for( int j = 0; j < OriginalImgSize.width - 4; j+= 200, Idx++ )
   {

       Mat mf( i,j, CV_32F, pdata + 200 );
       Rect roi(j,i,200,200);
       mf.copyTo( big(roi) );


   }
}

imwrite( "testing" , big );
```

This gives me :

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!fixedSize()) in release
```

in `mf.copyTo( big(roi) );`.

Comment: What are trying to do exactly? just combine the 16 part which are float data into a one mat?

Comment: @Humam Helfawi: Yes.Just in the first case I want to be able to visualize every block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to know where are your subimages into the big image. To do this, you can save the `rect` of each subimage into the `vector<Rect> smallImageRois;`

Then you can use pointers (keep in mind that subimages are not continuous), or simply use `copyTo` to the correct place:

Have a look:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image");
    resize(img, img, Size(800, 800));

    Mat grayImg;
    cvtColor(img, grayImg, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    grayImg.convertTo(grayImg, CV_32F);

    int N = 4;

    if (((grayImg.rows % N) != 0) || ((grayImg.cols % N) != 0))
    {
        // Error
        return -1;
    }

    Size graySize = grayImg.size();
    Size smallSize(grayImg.cols / N, grayImg.rows / N);

    vector<Mat> smallImages;
    vector<Rect> smallImageRois;

    for (int i = 0; i < graySize.height; i += smallSize.height)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < graySize.width; j += smallSize.width)
        {
            Rect rect = Rect(j, i, smallSize.width, smallSize.height);
            smallImages.push_back(grayImg(rect));
            smallImageRois.push_back(rect);
        }
    }

    // Option 1. Using pointer to subimage data.

    Mat big1(800, 800, CV_32F); 
    int big1step = big1.step1();

    float* pbig1 = big1.ptr<float>(0);

    for (int idx = 0; idx < smallImages.size(); ++idx)
    {
        float* pdata = (float*)smallImages[idx].data;
        int step = smallImages[idx].step1();
        Rect roi = smallImageRois[idx];

        for (int i = 0; i < smallSize.height; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < smallSize.width; ++j)
            {
                pbig1[(roi.y + i) * big1step + (roi.x + j)] = pdata[i * step + j];
            }
        }
    }

    // Option 2. USing copyTo
    Mat big2(800, 800, CV_32F); 
    for (int idx = 0; idx < smallImages.size(); ++idx)
    {
        smallImages[idx].copyTo(big2(smallImageRois[idx]));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: :Excellent!Thanks!Just to clarify ( regarding my last comment from the previous post).Every smallmage (hence pdata ) has  range from 0-199 ,right?So , image 0 has 0-199 ,image 1 has 0-199 and so on.( upvoted)

Comment: Your subimages are not continuos (since refers to portion of the original image). For example, you see that for first subimage the first row has index from 0 to 199, while second row has index from 800 to 999. If you change the line to `smallImages.push_back(grayImg(rect).clone());`, each subimage is then continuous, and for the first one the first row is from 0 to 199, second one from 200 to 399

Comment: The code will work correctly in both cases, since you access `pdata` using `step`, and not `width`

Comment: :Hello!I have one question.I was expecting , using: `cout << "pointer = " << (pdata + 1)[ i * step + j  ] << endl;
 cout << "data = " << smallmages[ idx +1].at<int>(i*step+j) << endl;` to produce the same result but they don't.Don't `(pdata+1)` points to `smallImages[ idx + 1].data`?Thank you in advance!

Comment: Short answer, no. I'll explain this better asap

Comment: :If you can explain the above comment,it will help me!(I am working on the problem I have [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34162446/compare-pixels-and-sort],it is indeed a  puzzle solver!And as I can see it is very very hard!I think my post is wrong.I thought now ,to compute the histograms of every block (but only the histograms at the boundaries [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184319/substract-region-from-image-and-keep-the-borders] ) and compare them.

Comment: :But ,then I have to compare every direction (north,east..) with every other and how I can have the first piece in order?Anyway, I am just telling you my thoughts , I don't expect an answer to this).Thank you.

Comment: `(pdata+1)` points to `pdata[1]`, **not** to `smallImages[ idx + 1].data`. Working with raw pointers may be very difficult (and hard to debug), so may advice to avoid them (unless for very simple tasks) still stands.

Comment: You can see also in my attempt to solve the puzzle how to compute histograms on borders. Getting the (possible) relative position between pieces is quite easy. The global positioning is what doesn't work well in that answer. I planned to create a weight matrix of the probability that each piece is north, south, etc with each other, and then keep the positioning the maximize the total weight and provide a _valid_ solution.  Determine if the solution is _valid_ (id A is connected north to B, and C is connected east to B, then B cannot be connected south to C, etc... ) is somehow tricky.

Comment: I planned to come back on that question, but I didn't had enough time.

Comment: :Ok, so you suggest to stick with `smallImages[ idx ].at<int>(i*step+j);`.The puzzle solver is a difficult task and not for beginners in image processing as I can see now!Many thanks for your help.
`

Comment: No, I suggest to use "smallImages[idx].at<...>(i,j)", or "copyTo".

Answer (score 1):

For concatenating the sub-images into a single squared image, you can use the following function:

```
// Important: all patches should have exactly the same size
Mat concatPatches(vector<Mat> &patches) {
    assert(patches.size() > 0);

    // make it square
    const int patch_width   = patches[0].cols;
    const int patch_height  = patches[0].rows;
    const int patch_stride  = ceil(sqrt(patches.size()));
    Mat image               = Mat::zeros(patch_stride * patch_height, patch_stride * patch_width, patches[0].type());

    for (size_t i = 0, iend = patches.size(); i < iend; i++) {
        Mat &patch = patches[i];
        const int offset_x = (i % patch_stride) * patch_width;
        const int offset_y = (i / patch_stride) * patch_height;

        // copy the patch to the output image
        patch.copyTo(image(Rect(offset_x, offset_y, patch_width, patch_height)));
    }

    return image;
}
```

It takes a vector of sub-images (or patches as I refer them to) and concatenates them into a squared image. Example usage:

```
vector<Mat> patches;
vector<Scalar> colours = {Scalar(255, 0, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), Scalar(0, 0, 255)};
// fill vector with circles of different colours
for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    Mat patch = Mat::zeros(100,100, CV_32FC3);
    circle(patch, Point(50,50), 40, colours[i % 3], -1);

    patches.push_back(patch);
}

Mat img = concatPatches(patches);
imshow("img", img);
waitKey();
```

Will produce the following image

[image: Concatenating image blocks]

Comment: :Thanks for this but can you stick on my specific code ?

Comment: `Mat big = concatPatches(subImages);` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

print the values of `i` and `j` before creating `Mat mf` and I believe you will soon be able to find the error.

Hint 1: `i` and `j` will be `0` the first time

Hint 2: Use the `copyTo()` with a ROI like:

```
cv::Rect roi(0,0,200,200);
src.copyTo(dst(roi))
```

**Edit:**

Hint 3: Try not to do such pointer fiddling, you will get in trouble. Especially if you're ignoring the step (like you seem to do).

Comment: I edited the `Mat mf( i,j, CV_32F, pdata + 200 );` , if you mean the step.I used roi for copyTo.I still have errors.As for the i,j values ?I think they are ok?