# substract region from image and keep the borders

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a 200x200 pixels image and I want to keep only the data for a certain region inside it.
Check the following image:

[image]

The whole out square is 200x200 pixels.I want to remove from it the smaller square(white).So ,keep only the information that is included in the blue area.But , I want to keep the 200x200 dimensions.

I tried:

```
    Mat whiteArea;
    whiteArea = ImageInitial( Range(50,200) , Range(50,200) );

    Size size(200,200);
    Mat dst;
    resize(whiteArea,dst,size);

    Mat FinalImage;
    subtract(ImageInitial,dst,FinalImage);
```

I am resizing the white area because I want to substract it from the initial image.
My problem is that it gives me the initial image.

Maybe the resize is the problem .but then how to substract 2 different sized images?

Comment: so you want to subtract only the inner part of the image from itself? and that inner part goes from pixel location (50,50) to (250,250)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use subimages or use a mask:

```
// use a roi (nice if your target area is rectangular and you know the position)
Rect whiteArea = Rect(50,50, 200,200); // creates a roi of the inner rect

Mat FinalImage = ImageInitial.clone();
// now set the roi area to zero:
FinalImage (whiteArea).setTo(Scalar(0,0,0));
// or FinalImage(whiteArea) = FinalImage(whiteArea) - FinalImage(whiteArea);

imshow("version 1 with subimage", FinalImage);
waitkey(0);


// or use a mask (nice if that region can has arbitrary shape etc and you have to extract it first):
Scalar lowerColorBound = Scalar(x,y,z); //some BGR values to find the color you want to eliminate
Scalar upperColorBound = Scalar(a,b,c); //some BGR values to find the color you want to eliminate
Mat mask;
inRange(ImageInitial, lowerColorBound, upperColorBound  mask)
// use the mask for subtraction:
subtract(ImageInitial, ImageInitial, FinalImage , mask);

imshow("version 2 with mask", FinalImage);
waitkey(0);
```

Comment: :Great,thanks!( the 2nd version I wasn't able to run it because it gave me `Mat’ has no member named ‘inRange’`)

Comment: :Ok, it's working now ,thanks.I wanted to ask , in the first version ,can we fill the whiteArea `setTo(Scalar(0,0,0));` with garbage values?Nan values or something?And still have an image where I can do computations?( I  am just asking now! :) )

Comment: nan is only defined for floating point values. integer types dont know sth. like that. So either convert to float/double and set to nan or remember where you know garbage to be (e.g. a mask) and give that information to following processing steps (then it might be more  convenient to mask not the garbage but the "good" pixel)